# Enum/Type/string as keys in object Type/interface

Tags: typescript, object, types, enums, key

I am trying to choose the proper typescript construct for translation objects that I use in my app. They can look like this:

```
{
  'en': 'house', // English
  'es': 'casa',  // Spanish
  'pl': 'dom',   // Polish
}
```

In general they can have many more language codes than the above 'en', 'es', 'pl'. There will be around 200 in total. A given translation object does not need to contain all of these keys.

Here are my three approaches:

```
type LanguageCode = 'en' | 'es'| 'pl'

enum LanguageCode2 {
  'en' = 'en',
  'es' = 'es',
  'pl' = 'pl',
}


type Foo = {
  [key in LanguageCode]: string;
};

type Foo2 = {
  [key in LanguageCode2]: string;
};

type Foo3 = {
  [key in string]: string;
};

const o1: Foo = {     // TS2741: property 'pl' is missing in type....
  'en': 'house',
  'es': 'casa',
}

const o2: Foo2 = {    // TS2741: property 'pl' is missing in type....
  'en': 'house',
  'es': 'casa',
}

const o3: Foo3 = {
  'en': 'house',
  'es': 'casa',
}
```

The only of the objects that is transpiled correctly is o3, how can I make compile o1 and o2 correctly? Is there any other approach to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

```ts
type LanguageCode = "en" | "es" | "pl";

type LocalizationRecord = Partial<Record<LanguageCode, string>>;

const o1: LocalizationRecord = {
  en: "house",
  es: "casa",
};

const o2: LocalizationRecord = {
  en: "house",
  es: "casa",
};

const o3: LocalizationRecord = {
  en: "house",
  es: "casa",
};
```